# Magento language switch store code Urls

Tags: magento, multilingual

I have Magento 1.7.0.2

My problem is in language switch from store views.

I have enabled mod_rewrite, and enabled store code to urls.
But language switch doesn't work correctly.
Example : `http://mysite.com/en/` - Default page

When i want to change language in french the url in 
language switch looks : `http://mysite.com/en/?___store=fr`

And it doesnt works
I found that switcher is situated in:

`app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/page/switch/languages.phtml`

But i dont know how to change the code to make it work correctly.

When i want to change language, need to have this url : `http://mysite.com/fr`
without `?___store=fr`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved it. The problem was in languages.phtml because it was file of theme, so i changed it with default. now all works correctly.

Answer (score 7):

If you look into `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php` you see following function:

> public function getCurrentUrl($fromStore = true)

So without changing any core code grab `/app/design/frontend/base/default/
template/page/switch/languages.phtml`

Change the line

```
<option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
```

to

```
<option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl(false) ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
```

and put the changed file into the corresponding path of your theme folder.

And now you have clean URLs.